# SQL Sum() Aggregate using user input as parameter

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, aggregate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oDGw.png)I am trying to write an sql python query to find the monthly sum of a certain product i have stored in my database. My database file contains a column of each day of the year and the daily sale of each product.My query works when manually inputting the product column to search but i want the user to be able to input the column to search and display values for.

```
My query:



def plotter(self, title, index1):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()

    title = input("Enter column to search")

    aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute("""select SUM(?),
    strftime("%m-%Y", orderDate) as 'month-year'
    from groupedSales group by strftime("%m-%Y", orderDate)""", 
    (title,)).fetchall()

    valueArray = []
    valueArray2 = []
    for values in aggregateIndividuals:
        valueArray2.append(values[-1])
        valueArray.append(values[index1])
        print(values[index1])

title = input("Enter column to search")
plotter(title, 1)

E.g. title = 'Espresso'


To note: the index1 argument corresponds to the row number of the title 
name. I have a separate function to automate this so the customer need to 
only enter the product name.
```

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oDGw.png)

Comment: I have edited the with a picture link of my database table

Comment: which lib you use? should it -> select sum(%s)?

Comment: Hi tire0011. Could you explain further about the lib? I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: I need to ideally have it like sum(variable) in which the variable is inputted by the user @tire0011

Comment: Where is cur defined? you import a libary, which one?

Comment: This is a minimal reproduced example. I will edit my post to show some more to help with the logic @tire0011

Comment: @tire100. The (?) is a place holder for a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, parameterization is used for literal values not identifiers (i.e., names of tables or columns). You will need to run string interpolation such as `str.format()` to dynamically pass Python input variable to SQL query. However, such an approach can open up to SQL injection especially due to user input.

Instead, consider normalizing your wide format into long format. This is a more efficient, scalable storage structure and avoids using data elements (i.e., product such as *ColdDrink*, *HotDrink*) as separate columns. Any new product does not require restructuring table with new column. Then, you can run you parameterized query. To mimic the long table format, you can run the `UNION` subquery (or as CTE).

```
title = input("Enter column to search")

sql = """SELECT SUM(sub.sales) as total_sales,
                strftime("%m-%Y", sub.[Date]) as 'month-year'
         FROM 
              (SELECT [Date], ColdDrink AS sales, 'ColdDrink' as item
               FROM TotalDaySales

               UNION ALL 

               SELECT [Date], HotDrink AS sales, 'HotDrink' as item
               FROM TotalDaySales

               UNION ALL 

               SELECT [Date], Cake AS sales, 'Cake' as item
               FROM TotalDaySales

               UNION ALL 

               SELECT [Date], Smoothie AS sales, 'Smoothie' as item
               FROM TotalDaySales

               UNION ALL 

               SELECT [Date], DecafDrink AS sales, 'DecafDrink' as item
               FROM TotalDaySales
              ) AS sub
         WHERE sub.[item] = ?
         GROUP BY strftime("%m-%Y", sub.[Date])
     """

aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute(sql, title).fetchall()
```

Alternatively, using a Common Table Expression (CTE) via `WITH` clause, available in [SQLite 3.8.3](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

```
sql = """WITH sub AS 
          (SELECT [Date], ColdDrink AS sales, 'ColdDrink' as item
           FROM TotalDaySales

           UNION ALL 

           ...)

         SELECT SUM(sub.sales) as total_sales,
                strftime("%m-%Y", sub.[Date]) as 'month-year'
         FROM sub
         WHERE sub.[item] = ?
         GROUP BY strftime("%m-%Y", sub.[Date])
     """

aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute(sql, title).fetchall()
```

To be clear, ideally you do not use a `UNION` query but restructure table in long format:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TotalDaySalesLong AS 
  (SELECT [Date], ColdDrink AS sales, 'ColdDrink' as item
   FROM TotalDaySales

   UNION ALL 

   ...)
```